# What impact does changing a IReliableQueue to a IReliableConcurrentQueue have in an existing deployment?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am working in a Service Fabric application that uses IReliableQueue. For the uses cases of this system, the [IReliableConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-concurrent-queue) makes sense to use and some local testing (i.e. basically by just changing the code to use IReliableConcurrentQueue instead of IReliableQueue - queue name does not change) shows great performance improvements. However, I am worried about the impact of changing this in a production system (i.e. upgrading). I can't find any docs or online questions (unless I just missed them) about these considerations. For example, in this system, the existing IReliableQueue will almost always have items. So what happens to that data when I upgrade the SF application? Will it be available to dequeue in the IReliableConcurrentQueue? Or would data be lost? I know I can "just try it" but wanted to see if someone out there had done the same or could offer pointers to existing resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for a late answer *(that you probably don't need anymore but still)*.

When we calling `GetOrAddAsync` method on `IReliableStateManager` we aren't retrieving the interface to store values - we actually creating an instance of reliable collection. This basically means that type of the interface we specify is very important.

Taking this into account if we do this:

**Service v. 1.0**

```
// Somewhere in RunAsync for example
await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<long>>("MyCollection")
```

Then doing this in the next version:

**Service v. 1.1**

```
// Somewhere in RunAsync for example
await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableConcurrentQueue<long>>("MyCollection")
```

will throw an exception:

> Returned reliable object of type Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.DistributedQueue`1[System.Int64] cannot be casted to requested type Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.IReliableConcurrentQueue`1[System.Int64]

and then:

> System.ExecutionEngineException: 'Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.'

The above exception looks like a bug so I have filled [one](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1448).

---

**UPDATE 2019.06.28**

It turned out that appearance of `System.ExecutionEngineException` isn't a bug but rather an undocumented behavior of `Environment.FailFast` method in combination with Visual Studio debugger.

Please see my [comment](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1448#issuecomment-506737546) to the above issue.

---

This is what would happen.

There are plenty ways to overcome this.

Here is the most obvious one:

**Example**

```
var migrate = false; // This flag indicates whether the migration was already done.
var migrateValues = new List<long>();

var applicationFlags = await this.StateManager
    .GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, bool>>("application-flags");
using (var transaction = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
{
    var flag = await applicationFlags
        .TryGetValueAsync(transaction, "queue-to-concurrent-queue-migration");
    if (!flag.HasValue || !flag.Value)
    {
        var queue = await this.StateManager
            .GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<long>>("value-collection");
        for (;;)
        {
            var c = await queue.TryDequeueAsync(transaction);
            if (!c.HasValue)
            {
                break;
            }

            migrateValues.Add(c.Value);
        }
        migrate = true;
    }
}

if (migrate)
{
    await this.StateManager.RemoveAsync("value-collection");

    using (var transaction = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {
        var concurrentQueue = await this.StateManager
            .GetOrAddAsync<IReliableConcurrentQueue<long>>("value-collection");

        foreach (var i in migrateValues)
        {
            await concurrentQueue.EnqueueAsync(transaction, i);
        }

        await applicationFlags.AddOrUpdateAsync(
            transaction,
            "queue-to-concurrent-queue-migration",
            true,
            (s, b) => true);
    }
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
}
```

Please note that this code is just an illustrative example and should be properly tested before applying it to real life application.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I did still need the answer so I really appreciate it. I like the approach you suggested, another thought I have is to create a new queue instead and leave the old queue in place to be drained down while all new work goes to the new queue.